# Should text be bigger on mobile?

Tags: mobile, mobile-web, typography, font-sizes

Should text be bigger on mobile despite the fact that we're dealing with smaller screen real-estate?

Pros:

- Easier to read while in motion
- Easier to read under difficult lighting

Cons:

- Requires more scrolling

Comment: There's no one answer to this. Entirely dependent on many other variables. All that said, I'd never consider 'scrolling' a con in most situations. Plenty of studies have shown that users are quite capable at scrolling.

Comment: Too subjective, so impossible to answer. A better question would be how to calculate text size to achieve equivalent readability to text on a conventional monitor.

Answer (score 9):

[Jakob Nielson](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/scrolling-and-attention/) and a large group of [other studies](http://uxmyths.com/post/654047943/myth-people-dont-scroll) suggest scrolling is not a con. Users are acclimated.

Put it into context. If you're sitting at a desk, the monitor is roughly 28 inches away vs. a [mobile device that is 12 inches](http://www.news-medical.net/news/20110713/Study-evaluates-viewing-distance-and-font-size-in-smart-phone-users.aspx).  Should it be larger if it's closer?

Four years ago, [Smashing Mag found](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/20/typographic-design-survey-best-practices-from-the-best-blogs/) the most popular body font size on the web was 13px.

Now, most browsers default to 16px (1em/rem = 16px).

Other things to consider for readability.

1. Font: serifs v sans serif. Sans-serif fonts are *generally* easier to read if smaller and on display.
2. X-Height: higher is generally more readable (Georgia and Verdana).
3. Line-height: generally set to 1.5 (or 1.5 times font size)
4. Characters per line: [In The Elements of Typographic Style](http://webtypography.net/toc/), Robert Bringhurst suggests somewhere between 45 and 75 characters.  However, on mobile, 35-50 is a good target.

These are basic guidelines that if you didn't loosely follow, would affect readability because user's rhythm, focus, and comprehension would be negatively affected.

*Added source for 12-inch distance claim on mobile device*

*[This article](http://ia.net/blog/responsive-typography-the-basics/) pretty much addresses the heart of your question and backs up many of my claims. Conclusion, smaller text on smaller screen because it's held closer.*

Comment: Regarding popularity:  just because something is popular doesn't mean it is good design.  Related reading:  http://ia.net/blog/100e2r

Comment: Just to put your comment into context: back in the day(4 years ago) 13px was the most popular text size, but iA challenged this notion by advocating for 100% font-size (16px) before it became the norm. Good add.